# Convert NULL to null when the data type is timestamp in the table in Talend

Tags: postgresql, null, timestamp, talend

I have an excel having a timestamp column wherein the data is **"NULL"** in some rows.
I have to load this data into a table which has the data type timestamp.
Since the data is in String format in some rows and other rows have timestamp , I am getting this error in Talend

> Unparseable number: "NULL"

How to convert the data which has records **"NULL"** to **null** and the rest of the data to timestamp which is as it is?

I tried using the below code using tjavarow but getting the error of incompatible data types.

```
if (TalendDate.isDate(input_row.HD,"dd-MM-yyyy") == true)
    output_row.HD = TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy",input_row.HD);
else 
    output_row.HD = null;
```

Comment: how about using tReplace / tJavaRow and replace the "null" with null; But that may give NPE.

Comment: I did try using tJavaRow to replace the "null" with null but the target table has timestamp as the data type,Excel has string data type in few rows and timestamp in other few. Even using TconvertType after conversion but not working as needed.